# What is the place of an electromagnetic field in the electromagnetic spectrum?

Tags: electromagnetism

What place should I give an electromagnetic field (produced by a current conducting coil) in the electromagnetic spectrum? What will its wavelength and frequency be?

Comment: is the current alternating or direct?

Comment: its direct current

Comment: in that case, there is no radiation, no waves.  Wavelength and frequency are undefined. maybe looking at this question would help http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4637/

Comment: if the current used is alternating then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For alternating current, the frequency would be the frequency of the current.  For example, in the USA, household AC current is 60Hz.  The electromagnetic radiation would be an ultra low frequency radio wave.

(wavelength) X (frequency) = speed of light

So 60Hz corresponds to 5000km.

For direct current, there would be no electromagnetic radiation produced by the current.